# yii2 bootstrap merged rows input text doesn't align

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

I'm using bootstrap with a framework yii2. When I try to merge two rows the input text doesn't align correctly with the first row. I already try with off-set but he doesn't do nothing.

[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div class="form-group field-cliente-numero required">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"><label class="control-label" for="cliente-numero">Número</label></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"></div>

                <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="text" id="cliente-numero" class="form-control inputNumber" name="Cliente[numero]" value="0004"></div>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="form-group field-cliente-nome required">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"><label class="control-label" for="cliente-nome">Cliente</label></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" id="cliente-nome" class="form-control " name="Cliente[nome]" value="queste">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="form-group field-cliente-numcontribuinte">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"><label class="control-label" style="width: 150px;" for="cliente-numcontribuinte">Nº Contribuinte</label></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="text" id="cliente-numcontribuinte" class="form-control inputNumber " name="Cliente[numContribuinte]"></div>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="form-group field-cliente-idtbsectoratividade">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"><label class="control-label" style="width: 150px;" for="cliente-idtbsectoratividade">Sector Atividade</label></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <select id="cliente-idtbsectoratividade" class="form-control inline-block " name="Cliente[idtbSectorAtividade]">
                        <option value="1" selected>Moldes</option>
                        <option value="2">Plásticos</option>
                        <option value="3">Rações</option>
                        <option value="8">Alimentar</option>
                        <option value="9">Quimica</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="form-group field-cliente-datacriacao">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"><label class="control-label" style="width: 150px;" for="cliente-datacriacao">Data Criação</label></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="text" id="cliente-datacriacao" class="form-control dataAlign" name="Cliente[dataCriacao]"></div>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div class="form-group field-cliente-ativo">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"><label class="control-label" for="cliente-ativo">Ativo</label></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="hidden" name="Cliente[ativo]" value="0"><label><input type="checkbox" id="cliente-ativo" name="Cliente[ativo]" value="1" checked> </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <div class="form-group field-cliente-morada">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6"><label class="control-label" for="cliente-morada">Morada</label></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="text" id="cliente-morada" class="form-control inline-block" name="Cliente[morada]" value=""></div>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="form-group field-cliente-email">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6"><label class="control-label" style="width: 80px;" for="cliente-email">Email Geral</label></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="text" id="cliente-email" class="form-control inline-block" name="Cliente[email]" value=""></div>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" >
                <div class="form-group field-cliente-telefone">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6"><label class="control-label" style="width: 150px;" for="cliente-telefone">Telefone Geral</label></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input type="text" id="cliente-telefone" class="form-control inputNumber inline-block" name="Cliente[telefone]" value=""></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <div class="form-group field-cliente-codigopostal">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6"><label class="control-label" style="width: 80px;" for="cliente-codigopostal">Cód. Postal</label></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <input type="text" id="cliente-codigopostal" class="form-control inline-block" name="Cliente[codigoPostal]" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div class="form-group field-cliente-localidade">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6"><label class="control-label" for="cliente-localidade">Localidade</label></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input type="text" id="cliente-localidade" class="form-control inline-block" name="Cliente[localidade]" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>


            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="form-group field-cliente-pais">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6"><label class="control-label" for="cliente-pais">País</label></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <select id="cliente-pais" class="form-control inline-block" name="Cliente[pais]">
                                <option value="1" selected>Afghanistan</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                     
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="form-group field-cliente-km">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6"><label class="control-label" for="cliente-km">Km&#039;s</label></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input type="text" id="cliente-km" class="form-control inputNumber inline-block" name="Cliente[km]">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
    <div>
        <div class="form-group field-cliente-observacoes">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"><label class="control-label" for="cliente-observacoes">Observações</label></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"></div>

                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <textarea id="cliente-observacoes" class="form-control" name="Cliente[observacoes]" rows="4" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you are using rows, col-md-* then, why using width in style ??

Comment: Hey Man, Before different code was there. Now different. Atleast align properly @fabio.

Comment: In a row you can do 12 partition. You used col-xs-6, col-xs-6 and col-xs-12 which is 24 partition. Which is wrong .

Answer (score 0):

I dont think such an allignment is possible here.
You first two input in first row constitues total of 5 out of 12 in grid.

In next two lines you are trying to divide 7 original grids to 12.That means your col-md-1 in second and third row will be 7/12th (.5833) of your first line's col-md-1.

You need some thing like col-md-8.57 in second row to align it with the first row.Which is impossible.